# PowerShell: write-output only writes one object

Tags: powershell

I'm learning PowerShell and a vast number of articles I read strongly discourages the use of write-host telling me it's "bad practice" and almost always, the output can be displayed in another way.

So, I'm taking the advice and try to avoid use of write-host. One suggestion I found was to use write-output instead. As far as I understand, this puts everything in a pipeline, and the output is executed at the end of the script (?).

However, I have problems outputting what I want. This example demonstrates the issue:

```
$properties = @{'OSBuild'="910ef01.2.8779";
                'OSVersion'="CustomOS 3";
                'BIOSSerial'="A5FT-XT2H-5A4B-X9NM"}
$object = New-Object –TypeName PSObject –Prop $properties
Write-output $object

$properties = @{'Site'="SQL site";
                'Server'="SQL Server";
                'Database'="SQL Database"}
$object = New-Object –TypeName PSObject –Prop $properties
Write-Output $object
```

This way I get a nice output of the first object displaying the OS data, but the second object containing the SQL data is never displayed. I've tried renaming the variable names, and a bunch of other different stuff, but no luck.

While troubleshooting this problem, I found similar problems with suggestions to just replace write-output with write-host. This gets me very confused. Why are some people strongly discouraging write-host, while other people encourage it?

And how exactly do I output these two objects in a fashionably manner? I do not fully understand the pipeline mechanism of write-output.

Comment: I've tried this on Powershell v4 any they both output the same way, as a 3 column table.

Comment: @sean OK, thanks for the info. I'm using PowerShell v5 and it's not working for me. Very annoying.

Comment: `.\ScriptName.ps1 | Format-List`

Comment: @PetSerAl That simple. Thank you.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

- Just to clarify: **the problem is only a *display* problem**:

  - *When outputting to the console*, **if the *first* object is *table-formatted* (if `Format-Table` is applied, which happens *implicitly* in your case), the display columns are *locked in* based on that first object's properties**.
    Since your second output object *shares no properties* with the first one, it contributes nothing to the table display and is therefore effectively invisible.
  - By contrast, if you *programmatically process* the script's output - assign it to a variable or send its output through the pipeline to another command - both objects will be there.

    - See [Charlie Joynt's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40263087/45375) for a helpful example of assigning the two output objects to separate variables.
- The **simplest solution** to the display problem is to **explicitly *format for display* each  input object *individually*** - see below.

---

For a given *single* object inside a script, you can **force formatted to-display (to-host) output with `Out-Host`**:

```sh
$object | Out-Host # same as: Write-Output $object | Out-Host
```

Note, however, that this **outputs *directly and invariably to the console only*** and the object is then not part of the script's *data output* (the objects written to the *success output stream*, the stream with index `1`).
In other words: if you try to assign the script's output to a variable or send its output to another command in a pipeline, that object won't be there.

<sup>See below for why `Out-Host` is preferable to `Write-Host`, and why it's better to avoid `Write-Host` in most situations.</sup>

To **apply the technique ad hoc to a given script's output as a whole, so as to make sure you see *all* output objects**, use:

```
./some-script.ps1 | % { $_ | Out-String }  # % is the built-in alias of ForEach-Object
```

Note that here too you could use `Out-Host`, but the advantage of using `Out-String` is that it still allows you to capture the for-display representation in a file, if desired.

Here's a simple helper function (filter) that you can put in your `$PROFILE`:

```
# Once defined, you can use: ./some-script.ps1 | Format-Each
Filter Format-Each { $_ | Out-String }
```

<sup>[PetSerAl's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4003407/petseral) suggestion - `./some-script.ps1 | Format-List` - works in principle too, but it switches the output from the usual *table*-style output to *list*-style output, with each property listed on its own line, which may be undesired.

Conversely, however, `Format-Each`, if an output object is (implicitly) table-formatted, prints a *header* for *each* object.</sup>

---

#### Why `Write-Output` doesn't help:

`Write-Output` doesn't help, because it writes to where output objects go by default anyway: the aforementioned success output stream, where *data* should go.

If the output stream's objets aren't redirected or captured in some form, they are sent to the host by default (typically, the *console*), where the automatic formatting is applied.

Also, use of `Write-Output` is rarely *necessary*, because simply *not capturing or redirecting* a command or expression *implicitly* writes to the success stream; another way of putting it:
`Write-Output` is *implied*.

Therefore, the following two statements are equivalent:

```
Write-Output $object  # write $object to the success output stream
$object               # same; *implicitly* writes $object to the success output stream
```

---

#### Why use of [`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host) is ill-advised, both here and often in general:

Assuming you do know the implications of using `Write-Host` in general - see below - you *could* use it for the problem at hand, but **`Write-Host` applies simple `.ToString()` formatting to its input**, which does *not* give you the nice, multi-line formatting that PowerShell applies by default.
Thus, `Out-Host` (and `Out-String`) were used above, because they *do* apply the same, friendly formatting.

Contrast the following two statements, which print a hash-table (`[hashtable]`) literal:

```
# (Optional) use of Write-Output: The friendly, multi-line default formatting is used.
# ... | Out-Host and ... | Out-String would print the same.
PS> Write-Output @{ foo = 1; bar = 'baz' }

Name                           Value
----                           -----
bar                            baz
foo                            1

# Write-Host: The hashtable's *entries* are *individually* stringified
#             and the result prints straight to the console.
PS> Write-Host @{ foo = 1; bar = 'baz' }

System.Collections.DictionaryEntry System.Collections.DictionaryEntry
```

`Write-Host` did two things here, which resulted in near-useless output:

- The `[hashtable]` instance's entries were *enumerated* and each entry was individually stringified.
- The `.ToString()` stringification of hash-table entries (key-value pairs) is `System.Collections.DictionaryEntry`, i.e., simply the *type name* of the instance.

**The primary reasons for avoiding `Write-Host` *in general* are**:

- It outputs directly to the host (console) rather than to PowerShell's success output stream.

  - As a beginner, you may mistakenly think that `Write-Host` is for writing *results* (data), but it isn't.
- In bypassing PowerShell's system of streams, `Write-Host` output cannot be *redirected* - that is, it can neither be  *suppressed* nor *captured* (in a file or variable).

  - That said, starting with PowerShell v5.0, you *can* now redirect its output via the newly introduced *information stream* (number `6`; e.g., `./some-script.ps1 6>write-host-output.txt`); however, that stream is more properly used with the new `Write-Information` cmdlet.
    By contrast, `Out-Host` output still cannot be redirected.

That leaves just the following **legitimate uses of `Write-Host`**:

- **Creating end-user prompts and colored for-display-only representations**:

  - Your script may have interactive prompts that solicit information from the user; using `Write-Host` - optionally with coloring via the `-ForegroundColor` and `-BackgroundColor` parameters - is appropriate, given that prompt strings should not become part of the script's output and users also provide their input via the host (typically via `Read-Host`).
  - Similarly, you can use `Write-Host` with selective coloring to explicitly create friendlier *for-display-only* representations.
- **Quick prototyping**: If you want a quick-and-dirty way to write status/diagnostic information directly to the console without interfering with a script's *data* output.

  - However, it is generally better to use [`Write-Verbose`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-verbose) and [`Write-Debug`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-debug) in such cases.

Answer (score 2):

Generally speaking the expectation is for script/functions to return a single "type" of object, often with many instances. For example, `Get-Process` returns a load of processes, but they all have the same fields. As you'll have seen from the tutorials, etc. you can then pass the output of `Get-Process` along a pipeline and process the data with subsequent cmdlets.

In your case you are returning two different types of object (i.e. with two different sets of properties). PS outputs the first object, but not the second one (which doesn't match the first) as you discovered. If you were to add extra properties to the first object that match those used in the second one, then you'd see both objects.

`Write-Host` doesn't care about this sort of stuff. The push-back against using this is mainly to do with (1) it being a lazy way to give feedback about script progress, i.e. use `Write-Verbose` or `Write-Debug` instead and (2) it being imperfect when it comes to passing objects along a pipeline, etc.

> Clarification on point (2), helpfully raised in the comments to this answer:
>
> `Write-Host` is not just imperfect with respect to the pipeline /
>   redirection / output capturing, you simply cannot use it for that in
>   PSv4 and earlier, and in PSv5+ you have to awkwardly use `6>`; also,
>   `Write-Host` stringifies with `.ToString()`, which often produces
>   unhelpful representations

If your script is really just meant to print data to the console then go ahead and `Write-Host`.

Alternatively, you *can* return multiple objects from a script or function. Using `return` or `Write-Output`, just return object objects comma-separated. For example:

*Test-WriteOutput.ps1*

```
$object1 = [PSCustomObject]@{
  OSBuild = "910ef01.2.8779"
  OSVersion = "CustomOS 3"
  BIOSSerial = "A5FT-XT2H-5A4B-X9NM"
}

$object2 = [PSCustomObject]@{
  Site = "SQL site"
  Server= "SQL Server"
  Database="SQL Database"
}

Write-Output $object1,$object2
```

The run the script, assigning the output into two variables:

```
$a,$b = .\Test-WriteOutput.ps1
```

You'll see that **$a** is **$object1** and **$b** is **$object2**.

Comment: Thank you, this is clarifies a lot. Essential and precise details, which I find many tutorials lack.

Comment: Great answer; two quibbles: (a) `Write-Host` is not just _imperfect_ with respect to the pipeline / redirection / output capturing, you simply _cannot use it for that_ in PSv4- (and in PSv5+ you have to awkwardly use `6>`); also, `Write-Host` stringifies with `.ToString()`, which often produces unhelpful representations.
(b) While writing all output objects with a single statement may be good practice, it is not a requirement; all (possibly implicit) output commands scattered throughout a  script / function contribute to the latter's output.

Answer (score 0):

use write-host, write-output is for pipeline (and by default on console after clear)

Comment: OK, any thoughts on why many people will discourage this? Because that's mostly what I find online: "Never use write-host".

Comment: I do not see why ... There is always someone to tell you not to use by purism language elements. For you to make your choice :)