# PowerShell storing Get-Content into variable returns no data

Tags: xml, powershell

I have a very simple script that grabs the content from an XML file and returns it but is not working:

```
$DataFile = Get-ChildItem \\$Server\C$\ *.data -Name
[xml]$DataFileContent = Get-Content Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\$Server\C$\$DataFile
Write-Host $DataFileContent
```

This script is not returning any data on the Write-Host, but the following is returning the correct data:

```
$DataFile = Get-ChildItem \\$Server\C$\ *.data -Name
Get-Content Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::\\$Server\C$\$DataFile
```

Yes, the file is an xml file and the file exists. I'm sure I am missing something, but not sure what it is. Any help will be appreciated

Comment: If there are more than one files in the folder then $DataFile will be an array. I'm not positive exaclty how Get-Content will handle that but based on what you say works, it just gets the content of all the files and passes that down the line. In which case it would not be valid XML at that point. Is there more than 1 file in the folder?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use `Write-Host` here since you're trying to display an `[xml]` object. Try `write-output` instead.

If you require `Write-Host`, you would need to represent the object as a string beforehand or use a property that outputs a string. For example:

```
[xml]$x = Get-Content y.xml
Write-Host $x.InnerXml
```

This may be a good idea to use with write-output, as well.

Comment: Yet another reason to avoid `Write-Host`.  You do not need to use `Write-Output` however.  You can just leave it on its own line and it achieves the same thing: `$x.InnerXml`

Comment: I simply wrote that to increase verbosity as I believe they accomplish the same thing

Comment: There is no `I believe` here, they *do* do the same thing.

Comment: It's not a good idea to present `Write-Output` as an alternative to `Write-Host` without mentioning that they serve very different purposes. There is no strict need to convert objects to strings before passing them to `Write-Host`, but the use with non-strings can indeed result in near-useless or even downright confusing output, as in this case (empty or blank), because `Write-Host` performs `.ToString()` formatting combined with (potentially recursive) enumeration. However, note that  even [implied] `Write-Output` produces only marginally more helpful output for `[xml]` instances.

Comment: Hm - i was using `InnterText` instead of `InnerXml`

Answer (score 0):

First things first: **`Write-Host` has few legitimate uses in general** - do *not* use it to output *data*: `Write-Host`'s output goes straight to the *console* and can therefore neither be sent through the pipeline, nor captured, nor redirected (loosely speaking; for the full story, see the last section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50416448/45375) of mine).

**If your intent is to print a friendly representation of an object *for display only*, use `Out-Host` rather than `Write-Host`**, because the latter does *not* apply PowerShell's usual, friendly output formatting.

```
$DataFileContent | Out-Host # print object *for display only*
```

**If your intent is to output *data*, you can rely on PowerShell's *implicit* output behavior**, which sends any output that is not explicitly captured or redirected to the success output stream, which by default prints to the console using friendly formatting:

```
$DataFileContent # same as: Write-Output $DataFileContent
```

**Explicit use of `Write-Output` is rarely needed.** A notable exception is if you want to output a collection *as a single object*, using `-NoEnumerate`.

<sup>Note: Instances of `[xml]` happen to have only semi-friendly default output formatting that provides no insight into the document structure; to see the latter, access the `.OuterXml` property, though you may additionally want to apply pretty-printing, which requires more work.</sup>

---

`Write-Host` output differs from `Out-Host` and implicit / `Write-Output` output that prints to the console as follows:

- Instead of applying PowerShell's default output formatting, `Write-Host` essentially calls the `.ToString()` method on its input, which results in different, often near-useless representations - with the notable exception of *string* input.
- Additionally, `Write-Host` *enumerates* the input objects, if applicable,  so that a given input object's *elements* are *individually* stringified.
  An input object is considered enumerable if it implements the `[System.Collections.IEnumerable]` interface.
  This enumeration happens *recursively*, which in the case of `[xml]` instances results in output that is not only *useless*, but also *confusing* - see below.

`[xml]` instances, which represent XML documents, are enumerable, and *so are their enumerated elements (XML nodes), recursively*.

`Write-Host` *recursively* enumerates the top-level nodes of the document - which is either the root element alone, or, additionally, if present, the XML declaration - and invariably hits one or more *leaf* nodes, whose enumeration is invariably *empty* and yields the empty string.
Given that `Write-Host` separates the stringification of its (enumerated) input objects with a space each, you either get the empty string or one or more spaces as the overall output.