# How to filter an object of devices to a single one based on hostname in powershell?

Tags: powershell, stdout, write-host

I'm trying to get the sitename of a device by using the hostname of a single device from an object that contains the details of 100's of devices in Powershell. How do I filter it?

The data is originally from an API and is being pulled in as Json, I've converted it using `ConvertFrom-Json` so it should be in an object now.

I have tried piping the object through `Select-Object` and `Where-Object` unsuccessfully, the way I'm using the commands don't seem to do anything but I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

The data is initially pulled using:

```
$allDevices = New-AemApiRequest @params -ApiAccessToken $apiAccessToken
```

And is then converted to an object using:

```
$allDevicesObj = $allDevices | ConvertFrom-Json
```

The results of that can then be seen using:

```
Write-Host $allDevicesObj.devices
```

Which will show data similar to this:

```
@{id=1234; uid=123-456-789; siteId=1; siteUid=11aa; siteName=site1; deviceType=; hostname=DESKTOP-abc123;}
@{id=2345; uid=987-654-321; siteId=2; siteUid=22bb; siteName=site2; deviceType=; hostname=DESKTOP-abc456;} 
@{id=3456; uid=234-345-456; siteId=3; siteUid=33bb; siteName=site3; deviceType=; hostname=DESKTOP-abc789;}
```

I want to be able to filter the output to 1 of the results based on the hostname, so I tried using a combination of the `Where-Object` and `Select-Object` functions:

```
Write-Host $allDevicesObj.devices | Where-Object {$_.hostname -eq DESKTOP-abc123}
```

That just seems to do nothing and displays everything again. I tried being a bit less specific, but to also only select the siteName:

```
Write-Host $allDevicesObj.devices | Where-Object -Contains "123" | Select-Object -Property siteName
```

But that just showed everything again too. I tried similar variants with `Select-Object` with the same results.

When using the `Where-Object` to specify the object I want and then to just select the siteName value/property using `Select-Object` I am hoping to get the output to just be

```
site1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Write-Host writes a string representation of your object to the console and doesn't send anything down the pipeline. Filter using Where-Object and just allow it to be written to the Output stream.

```
$allDevicesObj | Where-Object {$_.hostname -eq 'DESKTOP-abc123'}
```

To get just the site you can pipe from where-object to select-object

```
$allDevicesObj | Where-Object {$_.hostname -eq 'DESKTOP-abc123'} | Select-Object -property SiteName
```

Comment: Ah, I did not know that about Write-Host. Thank you, that did exactly what I needed.

Comment: @Weighsone [`Write-Host` is typically the wrong tool to use](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/), unless the intent is to write _to the display only_, bypassing the success output stream and with it the ability to send output to other commands, capture it in a variable, redirect it to a file. In PSv5+ `Write-Host` writes to the [information stream](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection), whose output _can_ be captured, but only via `6>`. See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/50416448/45375