# PowerShell read variables from text file

Tags: powershell

I try to make a program that gets variables from an external file. My problem is that company policy doesn't allow users to run ps1 files (the program works because I compile the ps1 into an exe by ps2exe), so this external file must be a txt, csv, or something other plain text format. I don't want to burn these variables into the exe, because the users need some flexibility with the values they use.

I tried to make a hashtable and get the variables into it by ConvertFrom-StringData, but that messes up the output.

file.txt

```
one = foo
two = bar
```

prog.ps1

```
$variable = Get-Content ".\file.txt" | Out-String | ConvertFrom-StringData
Write-Host $variable.one
Write-Host "$variable.two"
```

The latter one shows up as: System.Collections.Hashtable.two instead of the value of $variable.two. Of course, in this simplified example there wasn't really need for the quotation marks around the second variable, but this program needs it at some places.

When I stored the variables with their correct format in a ps1 file, and inculded it the normal

```
. .\file.ps1
```

way, it worked like it should, but it can't be used by the users who need it.

I would appreciate any ideas of how to make it work. I mean if it's possible at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is merely the **incorrect use of interpolation syntax inside an expandable string (`"..."`)**:

`"$variable.two"` expands `$variable` *by itself*, followed by *literal* `.two`, because **in order to embed *expressions* in expandable strings you must enclose them in `$(...)`**, i.e., in this case, `"$($variable.two)"` - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40445998/45375) for a summary of PowerShell's string-expansion rules.

Perhaps surprisingly, `Write-Host $variable.one` - *without* enclosing `"..."` - successfully accessed the property value, because it is a *value expression* rather than an (implicitly) expandable string; [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41254359/45375) has more information about how *unquoted* tokens are parsed as command arguments.

Also:

- If you're running in PowerShell v3 or higher, `Get-Content -Raw` is simpler and more efficient than `... | Out-String` to get a text file's entire content as a single, multi-line string.
- As an aside: [`Write-Host` is typically the wrong tool to use](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/), unless the intent is to write *to the display only*, bypassing the success output stream and with it the ability to send output to other commands, capture it in a variable, redirect it to a file. In PSv5+ `Write-Host` writes to the [information stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection), whose output *can* be captured, but only via `6>`. See the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50416448/45375) for more information.

To put it all together:

```
$variable = Get-Content -Raw .\file.txt | ConvertFrom-StringData

'--- implicit output, to success stream'
$variable.one
$variable.two

'--- explicit to-host output, via expandable string'
write-host $variable.one
write-host "$($variable.two)"  # Note the $(...) around the property access
```

The above yields:

```
--- implicit output, to success stream
foo
bar
--- explicit to-host output, via expandable string
foo
bar
```

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is working, but you're using the wrong syntax for quoted variables.

It should be:

```
$variable = Get-Content ".\file.txt" | Out-String | ConvertFrom-StringData
Write-Host $variable.one
Write-Host "$($variable.two)"
```

For more information, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1145822/1385709).