# Parameter not being separated for foreach loop

Tags: powershell

I am trying to get monitor information from workstations.  When only one monitor my code works all right.  But on multiple monitors it fails.

```
$connections = get-ciminstance -namespace root/wmi -classname 
WmiMonitorConnectionParams
$videooutput = "$($($connections.VideoOutputTechnology))"

foreach ($output in $videooutput){
if ($output -eq 10) {write-host "DP"}
if ($output -eq 4) {write-host "DVI"}
if ($output -eq 5) {write-host "HDMI"}
if ($output -eq 0) {write-host "VGA"}
else {write-host "unknown"}
}
```

The issue is the output of the $ videooutput.  It returns multiple monitors like this:

4 10

instead of this:

4

10

So in a multiple monitor situation I get "unknown"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace `"$($($connections.VideoOutputTechnology))"` with `$connections.VideoOutputTechnology`.

`"$($($connections.VideoOutputTechnology))"`, aside from needlessly using `$(...)` *twice*, *stringifies* the array returned by `$connections.VideoOutputTechnology`, which by default creates a single string containing the (stringified) elements as a space-separated list.

As an aside, just to clarify: [`Write-Host` is typically the wrong tool to use](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/), unless the intent is to write *to the display only*, bypassing the success output stream and with it the ability to send output to other commands, capture it in a variable, redirect it to a file. (In PSv5+ `Write-Host` writes to the [information stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_redirection), whose output *can* be captured, but only via `6>`; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50416448/45375).)

Also, using a `switch` statement instead of a `foreach` loop with multiple `if` statements enables a simpler solution.

To put it all together:

```
$connections = get-ciminstance -namespace root/wmi -classname WmiMonitorConnectionParams
$videooutput = $connections.VideoOutputTechnology

switch ($videooutput) {
 10 { "DP"; continue }
 4  { "DVI"; continue }
 5  { "HDMI"; continue}
 0  { "VGA"; continue }
 default { "unknown"}
}
```