# How can i get the sum of a line from a .txt file in powershell?

Tags: powershell, text-parsing

So, I have a textfile "numbers.txt" like this:

```
2 3 4 5
5 6
6 7 7
6 88 9 67 4
65 76 979 8
6 88 5 4 23
```

My question is, how can i get the sum of each line?
What i tried to do:

```
$data=Get-Content -Delimiter " " numbers.txt
$data | % {
 $sum=0
 foreach($num in $_) {
 $sum+=$num
 }
 Write-Host $sum
 }
```

But it gives back weird numbers.
I dont know how to separate the different numbers in each line and get the sum of them.

Comment: As an aside: [`Write-Host` is typically the wrong tool to use](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/), unless the intent is to write _to the display only_, bypassing the success output stream and with it the ability to send output to other commands, capture it in a variable, redirect it to a file. To output a value, use it _by itself_; e.g., just `$sum` instead of `Write-Host $sum` (or use `Write-Output $value`, though that is rarely needed). See also: the bottom section of https://stackoverflow.com/a/50416448/45375

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a fast and concise PSv4+ solution that utilizes LINQ:

```
(Get-Content numbers.txt).ForEach({ 
  [Linq.Enumerable]::Sum([int[]] ($_ -split ' ')) 
})
```

- `(Get-Content numbers.txt)` returns the input file's *lines* as an array of strings.
- `.ForEach({ ... }`) executes a script block (`{ ...}`) for each input line.

  - `[Linq.Enumerable]::Sum(...)` sums the elements of an array (enumerable) of numbers.
  - `$_ -split ' '` splits the input line at hand (`$_`) into (string) tokens by spaces, and converts the result to an array of *integers* (`[int[]]`).

Here's a - slower - solution closer to what you attempted (works in PSv3- too):

```
Get-Content numbers.txt | ForEach-Object {  # Process each line.
  $sum = 0 # initialize the sum (implicitly of type [int])
  foreach ($num in $_ -split ' ') { # Process all tokens on the line.
    # Note: Because $sum is [int]-typed, adding the *string* token at 
    #       hand implicitly converts it to [int].
    $sum += $num  
  }
  $sum # Output the sum - do NOT use Write-Host to output DATA
}
```

Both solutions yield the following:

```
14     # 2 + 3 + 4 + 5
11     # 5 + 6
20     # ...
174
1128
126
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

> `Get-Content -Delimiter " " numbers.txt`

This splits your entire file into a *single* array of number strings, ignoring line boundaries.

Instead, you must use `Get-Content` as-is in order to process the file *line by line*, and then split *each line* into space-separated tokens to sum up.

Answer (score 0):

Turn it into a single array of numbers:

```
-split (get-content numbers.txt) | measure -sum | % sum

1473
```

Oops, sum each line:

```
get-content numbers.txt | foreach { -split $_ | measure -sum } | foreach sum

14
11
20
174
1128
126
```