# powershell outoput to a text file

Tags: powershell, text, file-io

This PowerShell function does exactly what I want when writing to the console using Write-Host, which I know does some default formatting. However, I cannot find any way to get the exact same output saved to a text file.

### Here is my function:

```
function Get-FileHashInfo
{

Param($mydir)

    foreach ($item in Get-ChildItem -recurse -file $mydir -force) 
    {
        $mypath = [string]$item.directory + "\" + [string]$item.name
        $myhash = Get-FileHash -Path $mypath
        Write-Host $myhash.hash $item.name $item.directory
    }
}
```

### Here is my console output:

```
F887266A20CAA2E44E63F1B4E26218FFD4D3541C7A7100ED9FBF3A45F03066A7 a.txt C:\data\tmp
6D21DED17244347CE2C02A96D5F81CED1CAB82343E26D7E3C57A00F0971B58C2 b.txt C:\data\tmp
2732A420088BBACD56DEB0E19D4EF5A28FA20F11B403ED3134EFDC0CC1EA0EC6 c.txt C:\data\tmp\subdir
```

I just need these lines to be written to a text file exactly as displayed on the console. However, no matter what I try, I end up with a lot of additional data in the output file, a messed up format,  or nothing in the text file at all.

Comment: In short: [`Write-Host` is typically the wrong tool to use](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/), unless the intent is to write _to the display only_, bypassing the success output stream and with it the ability to send output to other commands, capture it in a variable, redirect it to a file. To output a value, use it _by itself_; e.g., `$value` instead of `Write-Host $value` (or use `Write-Output $value`, though that is rarely needed). See also: the bottom section of https://stackoverflow.com/a/50416448/45375

Answer (score 1):

As [@mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60796140/powershell-outoput-to-a-text-file/60796287#comment107564018_60796140) pointed out in the comments, [`Write-Host`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-host?view=powershell-7) is not the right tool for this, as its *only* used for displaying purposes.

Here is a simple alternative that doesn't change too much of your original code:

```
function Get-FileHashInfo
{
    Param($mydir)

    & {
        foreach ($item in Get-ChildItem -recurse -file $mydir -force) 
        {
            $mypath = [string]$item.directory + "\" + [string]$item.name
            $myhash = Get-FileHash -Path $mypath
            "$($myhash.hash) $($item.name) $($item.directory)"
        }
    } | Out-File -FilePath ".\output.txt"
}
```

Which wraps your code in a script block and redirects the output to [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file?view=powershell-7). This Cmdlet is the PowerShell way of doing the standard output redirection `>` operator. It also saves *for-display* representations of its input objects, given that it uses the same formatting as in the console. You could also have a look at [Out-File: Using PowerShell to Redirect Output to File](https://adamtheautomator.com/out-file-powershell-redirect-file/) for a nice explanation on what `Out-File` does as well.

You also don't need to use [`Write-Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output?view=powershell-7) here, since supplying the string by *itself* is already good enough for passing it down the pipeline to `Out-File`. You could test this out by using `Write-Output "$($myhash.hash) $($item.name) $($item.directory)"` in the above snippet, and notice that it does the same thing.

Additionally, to call the script block you need to use the **Call operator** `&`, which goes into more detail in [About Operators](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7). If you don't use this, you will end up writing the `foreach` loop code block to the file.

---

**Update**

As [@mklement0](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45375/mklement0) helpfully suggested in the comments, Removing `Out-File` from the function and instead passing it down the pipeline to `Get-FileHashInfo` is a better idea. I wrote the earlier example just for quick demo purposes, but the snippet below is a better way of doing it. It also doesn't need to use a script block anymore, but demonstrating how to use it in conjunction with pipelines is good for learning purposes anyways :).

```
function Get-FileHashInfo
{
    Param($mydir)

    foreach ($item in Get-ChildItem -recurse -file $mydir -force) 
    {
        $mypath = [string]$item.directory + "\" + [string]$item.name
        $myhash = Get-FileHash -Path $mypath
        "$($myhash.hash) $($item.name) $($item.directory)"
    }    
}

Get-FileHashInfo -mydir "C:\test" | Out-File -FilePath ".\output.txt"
```