# Powershell - ForEach statement - concatenate results

Tags: powershell

I'm hoping to get some help from anyone here regarding powershell scripting.

I'm trying to see if there's a way to call all the results of the ForEach statement:

```
ForEach ($file in $test) {
        $filepath = $path+"\"+$file
        write-host $filepath
}
```

the write-host $filepath inside the ForEach statement returns the following:

```
c:\....\file1.txt
c:\....\file2.txt
c:\....\file3.txt
etc...
```

i'm trying to see if i can get all those results and put them into 1 line that i can use outside of the foreach statement. sort of like:

```
c:\....\file1.txt, c:\....\file2.txt, c:\....\file3.txt etc
```

right now, if i use write-host $filepath outside of the ForEach statement, it only gives me the last result that $filepath got.

hope i made sense.

thank you in advance.

Comment: As an aside: [`Write-Host` is typically the wrong tool to use](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/), unless the intent is to write _to the display only_, bypassing the success output stream and with it the ability to send output to other commands, capture it in a variable, redirect it to a file. To output a value, use it _by itself_; e.g., `$value` instead of `Write-Host $value` (or use `Write-Output $value`, though that is rarely needed). See also: the bottom section of https://stackoverflow.com/a/50416448/45375

Comment: yes, that's actually just the intent, i just add it to make sure i'm getting the correct info that i need.

Comment: @mklement0, this is at least a `Write-Output` icebreaker for me! :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing easier than that ...  ;-)

```
$FullPathList = ForEach ($file in $test) {
    Join-Path -Path $path -ChildPath $file
}
$FullPathList -join ','
```

First you create an array with the full paths, then you *join* them with the `-join` statement.  ;-)

Comment: hi olaf, is there a way to exclude last record from getting the ','

Comment: @Ralph I'm not sure if I know what you mean.

Comment: so it now gives me the output of the array. path\text1.txt,path\text2.txt, path\text3.txt etc but the last record also gets path\text12.txt"," which i need removed

Comment: does youre array have an empty element as the last one?

Answer (score 1):

Another variant,

```
$path = $pwd.Path   # change as needed
$test = gci         # change as needed

@(ForEach ($file in $test) { 
    $path + "\" + $file 
}) -join ", "
```

Answer (score 0):

You might also want to get a look at the FullName property of `Get-ChildItem`.

If you do `(gci).FullName` (or maybe `gci | select FullName`) you'll directly get the full path.

So if `$test` is a `gci` from C:\some\dir, then `$test.FullName` is the array you are looking for.