# Powershell -split needs to return a number not string

Tags: string, powershell, integer

I need to do some multiplication on the quantity in the string. I'm assuming that this is failing because the value is being returned as a string and not a number. The main body of this returns a 1 for the quantity but it falls apart on the multiplication.

```
720 * ([int]{
    $Inputstring ="Monthly Server Rental X 1 = $28.00"
    $CharArray =$InputString.Split(" ")
    $String1= $CharArray[4]; 
    write-host $String1
})
```

Comment: you're not returning anything. `Write-Host` writes to the host. `$string1` alone suffices, or use `Write-Output`, and it also doesn't need to be in a scriptblock `{..}`. This should be enough `[int](...)`. The type `[int]` defaults to `[int32]` as well, just as an fyi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A concise, PowerShell-idiomatic solution:

```bash
720 * (-split 'Monthly Server Rental X 2 = $28.00')[4]   # -> 1440
```

Note:

- A *verbatim* string (`'...'`) is used, so as to prevent interpretation of `$28` as a PowerShell variable whose name is `28`
- The *unary* form of `-split`, PowerShell's [string splitting operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split) operator is used to split the string into tokens by non-empty runs of whitespace, ignoring leading and trailing whitespace.
- While `-split` returns *strings*, the fact that the *LHS* is a *number* (implicitly of type `[int]` (`System.Int32`) implicitly *converts* the RHS to a number too.
- As [Abraham Zinala](https://stackoverflow.com/users/14903754/abraham-zinala) notes in the comments, [`Write-Host` is typically the wrong tool to use](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/), unless the intent is to write *to the display only*, bypassing the success output stream and with it the ability to send output to other commands, capture it in a variable, redirect it to a file. To output a value, use it *by itself*; e.g., `$value` instead of `Write-Host $value` (or use `Write-Output $value`, though that is rarely needed). See also: the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50416448/45375).

Answer (score 0):

DUH.

```
$Inputstring ="Monthly Server Rental X 2 = $28.00"; $CharArray =$InputString.Split(" "); [int]$String1= $CharArray[4]
$DUH = $String1 * 720
```

Could the split be cleaned up some? Seems like the $String1 could be incorporated in the split.