# The term '>>' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program

Tags: powershell

I want to run a powershell script and save/redirect the result to another file.
My script is:

```
# Define time for report (default is 10 day)
$startDate = (get-date).AddDays(-10)

# Store successful logon events from security logs with the specified dates and workstation/IP in an array

$slogonevents = Get-Eventlog -LogName Security -after $startDate | where {$_.eventID -eq 4624 }

# Crawl through events; print all logon history with type, date/time, status, account name, computer and IP address if user logged on remotely

  foreach ($e in $slogonevents){
    # Logon Successful Events
    # Local (Logon Type 2)
    if (($e.EventID -eq 4624 ) -and ($e.ReplacementStrings[8] -eq 2)){
      write-host "Type: Local Logon`tDate: "$e.TimeGenerated "`tStatus: Success`tUser: "$e.ReplacementStrings[5] "`tWorkstation: "$e.ReplacementStrings[11]
    }
    # Remote (Logon Type 10)
    if (($e.EventID -eq 4624 ) -and ($e.ReplacementStrings[8] -eq 10)){
      write-host "Type: Remote Logon`tDate: "$e.TimeGenerated "`tStatus: Success`tUser: "$e.ReplacementStrings[5] "`tWorkstation: "$e.ReplacementStrings[11] "`tIP Address: "$e.ReplacementStrings[18]
    }
} >> D:\test.txt
```

but I get errors like that

```
>> : The term '>>' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name, or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and 
try again.
At D:\Cyber_security\Python\Untitled1.ps1:26 char:3
+ } >> D:\test.txt
+   ~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (>>:String) [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

why this is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To address an *incidental* problem up front: even if you fix the redirection problem (see below), your `foreach` loop won't produce [*success*-stream output](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Output_Streams), resulting in an *empty* file. You're using [`Write-Host`, which is is typically the wrong tool to use](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/), unless the intent is to write *to the display only* (though in PowerShell 5 and above you *can* capture `Write-host` output if you *redirect it* to the success output stream, e.g. with `*>&1`). Instead, use [`Write-Output`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/write-output) (e.g. `Write-Output "foo"`) or, preferably, *implicit* output (just `"foo"`). See also: the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50416448/45375).

---

**[`foreach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Foreach) is a *language statement*,** and as such **you cannot directly apply a [redirection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection) (`>` or `>>`) to it** - see bottom section for an explantion.

You **need to wrap it in a (by definition [pipeline](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Pipelines)-based) *command* or *expression* first**, for which there are two options:

- *Streaming* option (preferred): Wrap the statement in a [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks) (`{ ... }`)  and call it via `&`, the [call operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#call-operator-) (or, if you want the statement to run directly in the caller's scope as opposed to a *child* scope, as created by `&`, use `.`, the [dot-sourcing operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#dot-sourcing-operator-))

  ```bash
  & { foreach ($i in 1..2) { $i } } > test.txt
  ```
- *Collect-all-output-first* option: Use `$(...)`, the [subexpression operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#subexpression-operator--):

  ```bash
  $(foreach ($i in 1..2) { $i }) > test.txt
  ```

---

Alternatively, use the [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) *cmdlet*, which *is* a command (as all named units of execution are in PowerShell), which also results in *streaming* processing (perhaps confusingly, a built-in alias for `ForEach-Object` is *also* named `foreach`, with the syntactical context deciding whether the cmdlet or the language statement is being referenced):

```bash
 1..2 | ForEach-Object { $_ } > test.txt
```

---

As for **what you tried**:

The [`>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Redirection) (`>>`) operator is, in effect, an alias of the [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file) cmdlet (`Out-File -Append`), and therefor requires a *pipeline* to function.

However, *language statements* cannot directly be used in a pipeline, and by themselves are always *self-contained* statements, meaning that whatever comes *after* isn't considered part of the same statement.

This becomes more obvious when you replace `>>` with `Out-File -Append`:

```bash
# !! FAILS, because `| Out-File -Append test.txt` is considered
# !! a separate statement, resulting in the following error:
# !!     "An empty pipe element is not allowed."
foreach ($i in 1..2) { $i } | Out-File -Append test.txt
```

The error message `An empty pipe element is not allowed.` implies that `|` was considered the *start of a new statement*.

The same happened with `>>`, albeit with the more obscure error message shown in your question, but you can easily reproduce it by executing `>> test.txt` in isolation.

- Note: Unlike POSIX-compatible shells such as Bash, PowerShell does *not* allow you to place a redirection *anywhere* within a statement, and fails if it *starts* a statement; e.g., `Get-Date >> test.txt'` works fine and even `Get-Date >>test.txt -Format g`, but `>> test.txt 'hi'` does not.

---

**Design musings**:

Given that an *expression* can serve as the - *first* only - segment of a pipeline (e.g., `1..2 | Out-File -Append test.txt`), it isn't obvious why a *language statement* cannot be used that way too.

The reason is a fundamental limitation in PowerShell's grammar:

- A pipeline by itself is a statement,
- but it cannot (directly) *contain* statements.

Hence the need to *nest* statements inside pipelines using the techniques shown above (`& { ... }` / `$(..)`).

Another unfortunate manifestation of this design is when you attempt to use language statements with `&&` and `||`, the PowerShell (Core) 7+ [*pipeline-chain operators*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Pipeline_Chain_Operators):

Since `exit` and `throw` are language statements too, the following idiom - which *would* work in POSIX-combatible shells - does *not* work:

```bash
# Exit the script with an exit code of 1 if the Get-ChildItem call
# reports an error.
# !! FAILS, because `exit`, as a language statement, cannot be
# !! used directly in a pipeline.
Get-ChildItem NoSuchDir -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue || exit 1
```

Again, *nesting* of the statement is required, such as `$(...)`:

```bash
# OK, due to $(...)
Get-ChildItem NoSuchDir -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue || $(exit 1)
```

Perhaps needless to say:

- This requirement is obscure and easy to forget...
- ... and it is exacerbated by the fact that placing e.g. `exit 1` after `&&` or `||`  does *not* cause a syntax (parse) error and only fails *at runtime*, and only when the *condition is met*.
  That is, you may not notice the problem until the LHS command actually reports an error.

  - Additionally, the error message you get when it *does* fail can be confusing: `The term 'exit' is not recognized as a name of a cmdlet, function, script file, or executable program`. This is because `exit` in this context is then interpreted as the name of a *command* (such as a function or external program) rather than as a language statement.

Comment: I tried the second option( **Collect-all-output-first option: Use $(...) ** )
but the output file is empty....after adding `*>&1 > test.txt` then the output is saved in the test.txt file.

Comment: Indeed, @ijahan - I missed the `Write-Host` problem. Please see the top of the updated answer. In short: `Write-Host` doesn't output _data_, it writes _to the screen_. Either use `Write-Output`, or, more simply, _implicit_ output (`e.g., just `"foo"` instead of `Write-Output "foo"`).