# Powershell - The result of the previous command is displayed

Tags: powershell

I have a weird problem with my script.

The goal is to display a summary of the configuration of a server, and everything went fine until I arrived to Firewall and Disk configuration.

So, if I enter this command:

```
Get-NetFirewallProfile | Select-Object Name, Enabled
```

It works, I have my Firewall status:
[FW_status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UHFP.png)

if I enter this command:

```
get-volume | Select-Object -property DriveLetter, FileSystem, {$_.size /1GB} | Where-Object {$_.DriveLetter -ne $null -and $_.FileSystem -ne "`O"}
```

it works too! I have my volume configuration:
[Volume_conf](https://i.stack.imgur.com/y6QdP.png)

But... If I use these commands in a script, it doesn't work anymore. If the FW command is first and volume command is second, I only have the result of the FW.
If the Volume command is first, and the FW command is second, I only have the result of the Volume!

For example, if I do:

```
Write-host "Firewall command" -backgroundcolor green
Get-NetFirewallProfile | Select-Object Name, Enabled
Write-host "Volume command" -backgroundcolor green
get-volume | Select-Object -property DriveLetter, FileSystem, {$_.size /1GB} | Where-Object {$_.DriveLetter -ne $null -and $_.FileSystem -ne "`O"}
```

I have this result:
[FW_first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ndI21.png)

if I change the order, I have this result:
[Volume_First](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WVCcQ.png)

```
Firewall command

Volume command
Name    Enabled
----    -------
Domain     True
Private    True
Public     True
```

I add that the problem is the same if I delete "Write-host" commands. I try on Powershell, Powershell ISE, and Visual Studio Code, and by using variables...Always the same result...

Does someone know what's going on, or what I do wrong?

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Mixing different object types doesn't work well with the implied running of format-table.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not so familiar with powershell yet... What do you mean exactly? Is there a way to pass throught it?

Comment: In other words, try to end both lines that start with `get`, with ` | Format-Table` (But I am  that this works too.... )

Comment: Thanks for your help, I don't fully understand this yet, but it gave me leads to solve my problem.
With the help of this topic: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40257475/powershell-write-output-only-writes-one-object
So, to make it works, I used " | out-host " after each command to display what I want.