# How can I convert text into a variable name in powershell

Tags: powershell, variables, indirection

I'm trying to convert text selected from a list into a variable name.
this is the testing code I'm using

```
$trees = @("oak","pine","teak") 
$fruit = @("apple","pear","banana")
$color = @("red","green","blue")


function list($items){
    foreach ($item in $items){
        Write-Host $item
    }
}
```

my goal is something like.

```
$select = 'color'
```

so I can use it as a variable, like this.

```
 Write-Host $select # should display 'red green blue'

 Write-Host $select[1] # should display 'green'

 list($select) # calling the function should display
 #   red
 #   green
 #   blue
```

this is some of the things i've tried

```
    $select = $'color'

    $select = $('color')

    $select = -join($'color')

    $select = Get-Variable 'color'

    $select = Get-Variable(color)

    $select = $(Get-Variable 'color')
```

I'm a complete noob with powershell so
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What you're looking for is _variable indirection_, where you refer to a variable _indirectly_, via its name stored in a different variable or provided by an expression. PowerShell enables this via the [`Get-Variable`](https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/get-variable) and [`Set-Variable`](https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/set-variable) cmdlets, but note that there are usually better alternatives, such as hashtables. See the linked duplicates for details.

Comment: Applied to your example: `(Get-Variable $select -ValueOnly)` and `(Get-Variable $select -ValueOnly)[1]`

Comment: Thanks for your fast reply. 
The 'similar questions' didn't help any but your answer was exactly what i needed, I was heading the right direction 
I had never heard of 'Indirection'. I'm 13 year old and I've only been using powershell for about 2 weeks.
 
This is what i've done with it
$select = "color"
$sel = (Get-Variable $select -ValueOnly)

# they all work as i wanted
Write-Host $sel
Write-Host $sel[1]
list($sel)

Comment: Glad to hear it, @ian. Note that the first two linked duplicates do show the same techniques that I summarized in my comment (except that the use of `[0]` on the result isn't spelled out, but that is incidental to the solution), whereas the third duplicate shows preferable alternative techniques that avoid indirection.

Comment: As an aside: [`Write-Host` is typically the wrong tool to use](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/), unless the intent is to write _to the display only_, bypassing the success output stream and with it the ability to send output to other commands, capture it in a variable, redirect it to a file. To output a value, use it _by itself_; e.g., `$value` instead of `Write-Host $value` (or use `Write-Output $value`, though that is rarely needed). See also: the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50416448/45375).

Comment: I may have misunderstood: Were you referring to the _related_ questions automatically suggested below your question? Yes, they aren't always helpful, especially if the terminology in the question doesn't match that in existing posts.