# Convert Json data into a hashtable and change data

Tags: powershell

I have a hashtable that I convert to a Json and back again

Now I want the host name “Server2” to have the description “Windows Server”.

Unfortunately the description cannot be changed. Maybe someone has an idea

```
Code example

$Json = @(
    @{ Hostname = 'Server1'; Description = 'Windows2022' }
    @{ Hostname = 'Server2'; Description = 'Windows2012' }
    @{ Hostname = 'Server3'; Description = 'Ubuntu_Server' }
)

$JsonData= ConvertTo-Json $Json 
write-Host($JsonData)
$Hashtable = ConvertFrom-Json $JsonData -asHashtable
write-Host($Hashtable.Values)

$hostIndex = $Hashtable.Hostname.IndexOf('Server2')
$Hashtable.Description[$hostIndex] = "Windows Server"

Write-Host($Hashtable.Description[$hostIndex])
```

My original data comes from a web server

This is just an example, which is why I convert the hashtable into a Json format and then back again

I tried to make a replacement

behaves exactly the same

Comment: Please just post the original JSON document you receive from the web server, it'll be much easier to help you solve your actual problem with that :)

Comment: `$Hashtable | ? Hostname -EQ Server2 | % { $_.Description = 'Windows Server' }` seem to be what you want

Comment: As an aside: [`Write-Host` is typically the wrong tool to use](http://www.jsnover.com/blog/2013/12/07/write-host-considered-harmful/), unless the intent is to write _to the display only_, bypassing the success output stream and with it the ability to send output to other commands, capture it in a variable, redirect it to a file. To output a value, use it _by itself_; e.g., `$value` instead of `Write-Host $value` (or use `Write-Output $value`, though that is rarely needed). See also: the bottom section of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/50416448/45375).

Comment: Another aside: PowerShell functions, cmdlets, scripts, and external programs must be invoked _like shell commands_ - `foo arg1 arg2` - _not_ like C# methods - `foo('arg1', 'arg2')`.  
If you use `,` to separate arguments, you'll construct an _array_ that a command sees as a _single argument_.  Therefore, for instance: `write-Host($JsonData)` -> `write-Host $JsonData`; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65208621/45375) for more information.

Comment: `$JsonData` is an array of hashes. `$Hashtable[$hostIndex].Description = 'Windows Server'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[lit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/447901/lit) provided the crucial pointer in a comment:

```bash
$Hashtable[$hostIndex].Description = 'Windows Server'
```

That is, given that `$Hashtable` contains an *array* of [hashtables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Hash_Tables) based on your JSON input, **you must select the target hashtable with an index *first*** in order to be able **to *update* its entries**.

By contrast, using [member-access enumeration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Member-Access_Enumeration) in the context of *lookup* via `$hostIndex = $Hashtable.Hostname.IndexOf('Server2')` worked as intended.

---

As for **what you tried**:

> ```bash
> $Hashtable.Description[$hostIndex] = "Windows Server"
> ```

- `$Hashtable.Description` applies member-access enumeration across the *array* of hashtables stored in `$HashTable` (given that your JSON input is an *array* of objects you chose to be parsed into hashtables via `-AsHashTable`).
- The result is a *dynamically created array* comprising the `Description` entry values across all hashtables, and this array *is no longer connected to the hashtables that the values come from*.
- *Assigning* to an element of this dynamically created array *technically* succeeds, but since the array *isn't captured anywhere*, the assignment is effectively *discarded*.
- **On a *general* note re *member-access enumeration***:

  - ***By design* it works only for *getting* property values / hashtable (dictionary) entries**, *not* also for *setting* them - see [GitHub issue #5271](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/5271).
  - Also, it **fundamentally only works with *dot notation***, i.e. via `.`, the [member-access operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Operators#member-access-operator-) (e.g. `$Hashtable.Hostname`), not also via *index notation* (e.g., `$Hashtable['Hostname']`) - see [GitHub issue #17514](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/17514).

---

**Taking a step back**:

As [Santiago Squarzon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/15339544/santiago-squarzon) points out in a comment, a **more PowerShell-idiomatic way** to achieve your goal is:

```bash
$Hashtable | 
  Where-Object Hostname -eq Server2 |
  ForEach-Object { $_.Description = 'Windows Server' }
```

This relies on the following:

- Hashtable instances are sent *as a whole* through PowerShell's pipeline.
- Hashtable *entries* can be accessed via *dot notation* (e.g. `.Hostname`) as an alternative to *index* notation (e.g., `['Hostname']`)

  - Using [simplified syntax](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Simplified_Syntax) with [`Where-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/where-object) (or [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object)), as in the command above, *implicitly* uses dot notation.
- By contrast, *assigning* to properties / hashtable entries is *not* supported via simplified syntax, so the more typical [script block](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Script_Blocks)-based (`{ ... }`) syntax must be used with `ForEach-Object`, acting on the current pipeline input object *explicitly*, via the
  [automatic `$_` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#_).